# Worksheet Change Event based on Message Box

Tags: vba, excel

My existing code uses ActiveX check boxes to modify the title and visibility of a worksheet in the Workbook based on cell "I16". What I want to do, is set a change event that will modify allow the worksheet to be further modified if the user changes the contents of Cell "I16" (Which is the title of the worksheet).

The code is intended to do the following:

- Confirm that the user intended to change the contents of cell "I16"
- If the user DID NOT intend the change, undo the change and exit the sub
- If the user DID intend the change, change the worksheet's name to the new name, ask the user if they want to clear the data from the previously named worksheet. (The idea here is that if we change the sheet name from Cookies to Cakes, the Cookies data will be cleared, even though the worksheet is still the same.)
- If the user wants to clear the data, the code will clear specific cell ranges from Column(variable) to the row above the LastRow (saving any formulas in the LastRow from accidental deletion)
- If the user DOES NOT WANT to clear the data, the code will leave the specified cell ranges alone, will set the new worksheet name, and then exit the sub.

The problem? The code does...nothing. I change the target address, and nothing happens. I tweak the code, adjust ranges, etc. and get nowhere.

Apologies in advance for the amateur coding you are about to witness, and my gratitude for your assistance in this.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Dim sheetName As String

    If Target.Address = "I16" Then
        If WorksheetExists(sheetName) Then
            Exit Sub
        Else
        MsgBox "Are you sure you want to change" & vbNewLine & "the name of this Allowance?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Confirm Name Change"

           If Yes Then
           Set ws = Sheet34
           ws.Name = sheetName

            MsgBox "Would you like to clear the data from" & vbNewLine & "this Allowance?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Confirm Data Clear"
                If Yes Then
                LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
                Worksheets.Sheet34.Rows.Range("C9:LastRow, -1", D9:LastRow, -1, E9:LastRow, -1, F9:LastRow, -1, H9:LastRow, -1, J9:LastRow, -1, L9:LastRow, -1, N9:LastRow, -1, P9:LastRow, -1).Clear
            Else
                Exit Sub

            End If
        Else
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Application.Undo
            Exit Sub
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: vbYes rather Yes, maybe? And as now mentioned below, capture response and compare.

Comment: Target.Address = "I16" is incorrect.  change to Target.Address = "$I$16"

Answer (score 2):

You do not capture the return value of `MsgBox`.

```
Dim result As VbMsgBoxResult
result = MsgBox("Are you sure?", vbOKCancel)
If result = vbOK Then
...
Else
...
End if
```